# How do you add borderRadius to ImageBackground?

Tags: react-native

The React Native `ImageBackground` component is supposed to accept the same prop signature as `Image`. However, it doesn't seem to accept `borderRadius`.

This has no affect.

```
<ImageBackground
  style={{height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 6}}
  source={{ uri: 'www.imageislocatedhere.com }}
>
```

How do you change the border radius of an `ImageBackground`?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

<sup>*This took some digging so posting Q&A for others to find.*</sup>

`ImageBackground` is basically a `<View>` wrapping an `<Image>`.
The `style` prop only passes height and width to the `<Image>`.

To pass other `style` props use `imageStyle`.

```js
<ImageBackground
  style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
  imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 6}}
  source={{ uri: 'www.imageislocatedhere.com }}
>
```

[The details are documented in the source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js).

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/57616397/1510435 instead.

Comment: This **is** the correct answer if you also use box shadow on the image background which won't work with the other overflow hidden answer.

Comment: This does not work anymore and link to documentation leads to 404 page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @SohaibShaheen. The code hasn't changed. They moved the location of the ImageBackground component in the repo. The link is now pointing to the new location. 

Answer (score 65):

Just add the property `overflow: 'hidden'`

```js
<ImageBackground
  style={{height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 6, overflow: 'hidden'}}
  source={{ uri: 'www.imageislocatedhere.com }}>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are planning to add content inside the ImageBackground item, then you should use J.C. Gras's answer.

> Just add the property `overflow: 'hidden'`

The reason is that if you use the `imageStyle` property as GollyJer recommended, then the content inside the ImageBackground won't respect the borderRadius, so it will loll out at the edges.

Comment: This worked for me